# QString to windows BYTE

Tags: c++, qt, byte, typedef

I've got a type BYTE which is defined in the windows.h header as follows:

```
    typedef unsigned char BYTE;
```

Then I've got some fields on a database which I get as QString and convert them to a QByteArray.

Currently I have:

```
        QString str = "0x168de78"; //some info from the database

        QByteArray tempB = QByteArray::fromHex(str.toAscii().toHex());

        BYTE *sequence = (BYTE*)strdup(tempB.data());
```

In this case the "0x168de78" stands for a sample of the information I am expecting to get from the database.

I need to convert the QString literally to a BYTE so I can later use it.

If I tell the app to give me the values of sequence and tempB.data(), I get something similar to this:

```
0x867dc8 "0x168de78" 
0x867de0 "0x168de78" 
0x867df8 "0x168de78"
```

So tempB.data() is alright, but sequence is not. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: BYTE *sequence = new BYTE[400]; - this is a memory leak, as strdup will allocate a new STRING. Why do you need a copy of the data?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?  how are you planning on using 'sequence'?  Are you actually trying to convert 'str' to a 32bit integer?

Comment: @neagoegab Thgank you for that, I corrected that part of the code.

Comment: @Pete The string is minutiae information extracted from a fingerprint reader. The funcions in the library for extraction, matching and verification, all relly on BYTE's. I need to gather all the samples of minutiae, load them into the memory and them match a newly created minutiae template with each template loaded into the memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
QString str = "0x168de78"; //some info from the database

QByteArray tempB =  QByteArray::fromHex(str.toAscii());//or 
//QByteArray tempB =  str.toAscii().toHex();

BYTE *sequence = (BYTE*)strdup(tempB.data());
```

Update: If u can use STL

```
unsigned int value;   
std::stringstream ss;
ss << std::hex << "0x168de78";
ss >> x;
```

Comment: I tested both methods, none of them worked. Now I am getting this on the console with the first method: 0x16c49e0 "hÞx" 
 and this with the second one: 0x145a168 "307831363864653738"

Comment: can you show how? Are you trying to convert from a hexazecimal string to a byte sequence and byte 1 should be 0x78, byte 2 = 0xDE?

Comment: well, I just thought that the casting could be done directly without the need of any other utility, apparently it is not.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I tried the STL method and it worked perfectly. Thank you.